# PHP if image exist in folder show else show default image

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a store with only 1 product image to see the store inventory, the image name is saved in the folder "product-images" using the same product code when uploading. Example

Adding a new product, the product code is 12345 I chose a image to upload and it get saved in the "product-images" folder as 12345.jpg

Now I show the images in the inventory list like this

```
<img src="product-images/<?php echo $show['product_code'] ?>.jpg" width="200" height="200">
```

It works fine but now if the product does not have any image I get the uggly empty image because the file does not exist.

So I want to do something like

```
if image exist in folder "product-images" show else show image default.jpg
```

How to check and do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you first need to check whether image exists like and then set the value. Something like:

```
$imagePath = "product-images/".$show['product_code'].".jpg";
if(!file_exists($imagePath))
    $show['product_code'] = "default";
```

of course, you need to have one default image in the folder product-images with name default.jpg

but maybe a bit better idea is to do like this:

```
$imagePath = "product-images/".$show['product_code'].".jpg";
if(!file_exists($imagePath))
    $imagePath = "product-images/default.jpg";
```

and then in html put just:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imagePath ?>" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Tested and it show only the default even if the image exist it show all as default.jpg

Comment: ah sorry, might be I forgot to put dot (.) before "jpg" -> ".jpg" in the second example. I will edit it.